# UNIX - How to write the NAME & PATH of files from different sub-directories into a single .txt file?

Tags: shell, unix

So I have a bunch of files in different sub-directories that I want to print the NAME and PATH of these files into  a single ".txt" file. This will be a recursive process as the files will be added daily and the ".txt" file will also be updated, so there is no fix amount of files. All the files will be in a ".txt" format.

For example:

C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\File has folders File1 and File2

File1 contains File1.txt

File2 containts File2.txt

I want the outcome in the ".txt" file to look like:

File1
C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\File\File1

File2
C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\File\File2

Can dir /B /S /O > list.txt for UNIX too? That provides the path but what can I do for just the file names?

Comment: Are you using a Unix os or windows? You mention the former but all your examples are for the latter...

Comment: And you just want the directories, not the files in them, in the result?

Comment: Using UNIX. I want the "path of the files" and the "file name" of the files within the directories in the result.

Answer (score 0):

To get a recursive list of all the files recursively you can use `find .`
To get both names and full pathes you can try something like:

```
find . | while read line ; do echo $line; realpath $line ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can dir /B /S /O > list.txt for UNIX too?

No, it works for window.

Try to use `find`. something like :

`find parent_path -type f -name '*.txt' > result.txt`